# std::algorithm Read access violation

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

I'm setting up the face detection with delay camera in opencv/c++. How can I do it without errors?

For detection I'm used CascadeClassifier.Detectmultiscale.

```cpp
void detectAndDraw(Mat& img, CascadeClassifier& cascade,

    double scale)
{
    vector<Rect> faces;
    Mat gray;

    cvtColor(img, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY); // Convert to Gray Scale 


    // Resize the Grayscale Image  

    equalizeHist(gray, gray);

    // Detect faces of different sizes using cascade classifier  
    cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces);

    // Draw circles around the faces 
for(int i = 0; i<=faces.size();i++){
//and cout of x,y,width,height
}
```

I have expexted the details but I have a error with Access Reading Memory in algorithm.

Photo:

[image: This is error]

Comment: mcWhat's the error you're getting? Post a [mcve] reproducing the problem please.

Comment: Always use text if you have the choice, as it is better readable, further processable, an generally accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have an off-by-one error in this loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= faces.size(); i++) {
   ...
}
```

That should probably be a `<` rather than `<=`, since otherwise on the last iteration your value of `i` will be out of bounds.

Comment: I contend that unless `i` is actually needed in the loop-body, it should rather be `for (auto&& face : faces) { … }`.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yeah, enhanced for loops are great in that they define away off-by-one errors.

Comment: But if I remove for (auto&& face : faces) { … } or other loop it giving me error too.

Comment: And with for (auto&& face : faces) { … } it isn't working too

Comment: I don't know how solve it. it says that it's in opencv_world310d.dll